# $X,Y,Z$ vector spaces, and $T:X\to Y$, $S:X\to Z$ linear maps. Then there exists $pi$ such that $T=S\circ \pi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be (any) vector spaces and $T:X\to Y$, $S:X\to Z$ linear maps with $\ker S \subset \ker T$. Then there is a linear $\pi:Z\to Y$ such that $T=\pi \circ S$

Obvious way to sort of define $\pi$ is to say for any $z\in S(X)$ we let $\pi(z)=\pi(S(x))=T(x)$. With the given condition we can check that this is well defined at least for $S(X)\subset Z$ and also that it is linear.

But I'm not sure how to extend this map to whole of $Z$ linearly

Comment: Any linear map defined on a subspace of a vector space extends (not uniquely) to the entire space. (Use basis extension.)

Comment: @Starfall Does that work for any vector spaces, not just for finite dimensional ones?

Comment: For arbitrary vector spaces, existence of bases depends on the axiom of choice. If you are allowed to use the axiom of choice, then yes, it works.

Comment: @PLE Another way is to consider $X / ker S \cong Image(S)$ via the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms and using that again you get an $\pi: Image(S) \to Y$. Setting the rest of $S$ to 0 you are done (no need for bases here).